# How to create a .csr file for only to a certificate that is going to expire in .jks file

Tags: ssl-certificate, keystore, weblogic12c, csr, jks

One of our certificate is about to expire and by using keytool explorer i selected the .jks file and in that many certificates are there and one is expiring. To renew that certificate i have exported the certificate by using the keystore explorer and got a .cer file. when i shared the .cer file to the client he asked to send the csr file.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be selecting the `Generate CSR` option for that key pair. This will generate the CSR that you need to send.

[image]

Comment: i just added the image of my expired certificate. Let me know in the image for the  expired certificate we need to create a keypair first and then need to generate csr or is there a way to generate directly the csr for the expired certificate in the image.

Comment: You cannot create CSR from a certificate. You need to do it form a key pair. Where is the private key of the certificate? Since the certificate is expired, you have 2 options here. You can generate a new key pair or use the old key pair. If you are choose to use the old key pair, you need to identify where it is. And then you would generate the CSR for it. If you choose to generate a new key paiar, you first generate it, and then generate the CSR.

Comment: thank you so much for the info. once i get the trusted certificate and after importing the certificate can i delete the keypair(new one) or it has to be there, which is best practice.

Comment: You SHOULDN'T be deleting the key pair for which you generated the CSR.

Comment: Thank you for your time